# CSRF Guard: How to hide CSRF token from URL

Tags: java, spring, web-applications, csrf, owasp

I have implemented OWASP CSRF Guard into my web application. Clien don't want CSRF token append on browser URL.How to avoid CSRF token in URL.

http://localhost:8080/abc/customer/userHome.do?OWASP-CSRFTOKEN=GRV3-6UN1-OACJ-1NFX-H1HP-OAIH-YSQZ-QXGA

I want userhome.do to be protected but don't want OWASP-CSRFTOKEN=GRV3-6UN1-OACJ-1NFX-H1HP-OAIH-YSQZ-QXGA in URL.

Comment: Put it in a cookie. Edit: If it's a POST request, then obviously you need to pass it within the POST body. If it's a GET, then why do you need to protect it with a CSRF token?

Answer (score 1):

You can save the csrf token on session and urls will be free of holding the csrf token

Comment: How we can do If we have implemented owasp csrfGuard. Any example